# making this Tabbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

How can I design this Tab bar in flutter?

[image]

Comment: What specifically do you need to know? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i dont know how to make the rounded edges

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounded Tab Bar in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63026849/rounded-tab-bar-in-flutter)

Comment: For more ideas, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340534/bottom-navbar-rounded-corners

Comment: Tab can be a custom widget tho, you can fully customise tabs.